# Joomla! 3.1, Remove Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, tooltip

I want to completely remove bootstrap from my Joomla 3 website, not to display tool-tips on the front-end. I tried almost everything and have read almost every article on the topic but cannot find the correct solution.

The fact is that it is not so hard to remove it but I want to remove it permanently so that no update can undo my changes.

Is there a way to complete this task?

Comment: are you using the prostar template that comes default with Joomla 3.1?

Comment: thanks for trying to answer, no, I use my custom template, and just found a solution that worked for me: on the very head of my custom template I put the code unset($this->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);

Comment: If it's a custom template, you don't need to unset it, you can simply remove the `JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');` reference and the CSS file, then use your own CSS file

Comment: @Lodder is dead on. If you are using a custom template simply don't load bootstrap.

Answer (score 6):

It is not enough to remove from template and modules few lines. 
My solution is to create a plugin:

```
class plgSystemYourPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
        // Application Object
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        // Frontend
        if( $app instanceof JApplicationSite )
        {
            $doc            = JFactory::getDocument();
            // Remove default bootstrap
            unset($doc->_scripts[JURI::root(true).'/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js']);
        }
    }
}
```

It works in Joomla! 3.2 - 3.6.

Comment: Waaaahooooo! Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can override jquery and/or bootstrap in your template. While not ideal, this solution worked for me: http://osdir.com/ml/joomla-development/2012-12/msg00475.html

Comment: Provide the code example in the answer itself. Link may expire and answer will be not applicable.

Comment: Also, just checked the link. This is dead link.